# Syntax for IF statement in Conditional Formatting two sets of criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

Goal:To see quota attainment based on tenure and dollar amount presented as a cohort. If the target is missed the color should be red. If the target is attained then it should be green. Using conditional formatting with a formula in excel

Conditions: If an employee is within the first 90 days the target is $1000, After the 90 days the target is $4250.

`=OR(AND($B3-E$2<90,E3<1000),AND($B3-E$2>91,E3<4250))`

This formula results in only picking up the first part and not the second part. Example:Tina on 5/1/2018 earned $1287 so she missed quota ( tenure greater than 90 days and amount attained is less than $4250) therefore the cell should be red.

Worksheet Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF($B3-E$2<=90,IF(E3<=1000,TRUE,FALSE),IF(E3<=4250,TRUE,FALSE))
```

This also has the advantage of taking care of the edge case where tenure is exactly 90 days (which you don't account for with your `AND`

Comment: Thank you very much this works i just had to add ABS on the sum of the dates.